# Why WriteAllText Method Saves XML with special Characters?

Tags: c#, xml

When saving the XML string as a file, I get a wrong output XML with special characters. The "<" and ">" tags are replace with `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively.

XML String:

```
<string xmlns="http://smartpark.com/">
  <DocumentElement> 
    <SpaceInfo> 
      <R_Numb>490</R_Numb> 
      <FirstName>Michael</FirstName> 
      <LastName>Jones</LastName> 
      <Unit>311</Unit> 
      <Type>RG</Type> 
      <Location>FLOOR 1</Location> 
      <Feature>C</Feature> 
      <Space>100</Space> 
      <Status>Assigned</Status> 
      <DateAssigned>2014-09-24T00:00:00-05:00</DateAssigned> 
    </SpaceInfo> 
  </DocumentElement>
</string>
```

Saving Method:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("testing.xml"), urlText,Encoding.UTF8);
```

Sorry guys here is the entire code snippet:

> string url = "http://smartparkllc.com/Service1.asmx/SpaceInfo?space=100";
>               //store XML returned by webservice 
>               string urlText = "";
>               //call webservice
>               WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
>               //get response from web service
>               using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
>               {
>                   using (StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
>                   {

```
                urlText = reader1.ReadToEnd();

                testweb.Text = urlText;//this is for testing. Can be remove   
                //create temp xml files from string containing XML returned by webservice
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("testing2.xml"), urlText,Encoding.UTF8);                   

                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(Server.MapPath("testing2.xml")))
                {

                    SpaceInfo newspaceinfo = new SpaceInfo();                      
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        //Only detect start elements.
                        if (reader.IsStartElement())
                        {
                            // Get element name and switch on it.
                            switch (reader.Name)
                            {
                                case "R_Numb":

                                    if (reader.Read())
                                    {
                                        //get value
                                        newspaceinfo.R_Numb = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value.Trim());
                                    }                                        
                                   break;
                                case "FirstName":
                                   if (reader.Read())
                                   {
                                       newspaceinfo.FirstName = reader.Value.Trim();
                                   }
                                    break;
                                case "LastName":
                                    if (reader.Read())
                                    {
                                        newspaceinfo.LastName = reader.Value.Trim();
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "Unit":
                                    if (reader.Read())
                                    {
                                        newspaceinfo.Unit = reader.Value.Trim();

                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "Type":
                                    if (reader.Read())
                                    {
                                        newspaceinfo.Type = reader.Value.Trim();

                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "Location":
                                    if (reader.Read())
                                    {
                                        newspaceinfo.Location = reader.Value.Trim();

                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "Feature":
                                    if (reader.Read())
                                    {
                                        newspaceinfo.Feature = reader.Value.Trim();

                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "Status":
                                    if (reader.Read())
                                    {
                                        newspaceinfo.Status = reader.Value.Trim();

                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "DateAssigned":
                                    if (reader.Read())
                                    {
                                        newspaceinfo.DateAssigned = reader.Value.Trim();

                                    }
                                    break;

                            }
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: XmlDocument.Save() maybe? In Your question original- and replacements are identical...

Comment: `File.WriteAllText()` makes no modifications to the text you are writing to the file. So if you are getting entity replacements in the XML represented by `urlText`, that's happened somewhere before the call to `WriteAllText()`. Unfortunately, you haven't provided a good code example, so there's no way to answer the question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I get the XML from a webservice with the code above

Comment: I tried XmlDocument.Save(), that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

If you have left and right brackets in your XML anywhere except tags, they will be encoded as `&lt;` and `&gt;`. This behavior is by design and called [escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents). When you read your XML back, those values will be unescaped, and you will see `<` and `>` again in .NET code.